# Setting BrowserSession in FeatureContext from BeforeTestRunHook SpecFlow

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

Beginner using SpecFlow and c# here.

I am trying to move my login steps from BeforeFeature to BeforeTestRun for a school project and I can't set the BrowserSession in the FeatureContext during the BeforeTestRun hook.

I am getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    public sealed class Hooks
    {        
        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void BeforeTestRun()
        {
        FeatureContextWrapper.BrowserSession = BrowserFactory.GetBrowser();
        }
    }
```

FeatureContextwrapper.cs

```
    public class FeatureContextWrapper
    {
        public static BrowserSession BrowserSession
        {
        get { return (BrowserSession)FeatureContext.Current["BrowserSession"]; }
        set { FeatureContext.Current.Set(value, "BrowserSession"); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the error, you wrote here, seems, that some instance is not initiated. But which - without more code/information hard to say.

Comment: Might be that in the `[BeforeTestRun]` the FeatureContext.Current property is null.

Answer (score 0):

try creating an instance of the class you created. Like this:

```
public sealed class Hooks
{        
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
        FeatureContextWrapper myWrapper = new FeatureContextWrapper();
        myWrapper.BrowserSession = BrowserFactory.GetBrowser();
    }
}
```